# How to fix the model.create() is not a function error in Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new with nodejs so please go easy on me.
I am setting up a nodejs server to connect to a mysql database using Sequelize.
I currently have an error "model.create is not a function" which I cannot find any related fixes on google.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

This is my model.js file

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Data = sequelize.define('Data',
        {
            oxyVal: {
                type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
                allowNull: false
            },

            mqState: {
                type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false
            },

            date: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
            },
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true
            }
        });
    return Data;
}
```

This is my index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Data = require('../models/data');

const app = express();
const port = 5500;


// I will now connect to my database

mySequelize = new Sequelize('Fast', 'root', '[password]', {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorsAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});

    // Test database connection here

    mySequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
        console.log('Database connected successfully');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error('Failed to connect to database \n ' + err);
    })

    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    //app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.get('/');
    app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
        const myData = Data.create({
            oxyVal: req.body.oxyVal,
            mqState: req.body.mqState,
            time: req.body.time,
            time: req.body.id
        }).then(JSON.parse(myData)).myData.save().then((result) => {
            console.log(result);

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });;

        res.send('Record successfully saved');
        console.log(myData);
    });



    app.listen(port)
    console.log("Server satrted on " + port + " .....");
```

Comment: Perhaps you should rename `models.js` to `data.js` (make the name of the file match the name of the `require`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your code working by doing the following 3 things:

1) rename `model.js` to `data.js` and putting it in the same directory as `index.js`.

2) change this:

```
const Data = require('../models/data');
```

To this:

```
const db = require('./data');
```

3) create a database 'fast', a user 'toor', with password 'password', and granted the 'toor' user full access to the 'fast' database. The connect line then ends up looking like this:

```
mySequelize = new Sequelize('fast', 'toor', 'password', {
```

Please take a look the sequelize CLI, it can help lay out your directory structure in a convenient way: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#the-cli

Comment: Thanks.I got it working by redefining my data.js model in a convenient way.